# Why my webapp and its data not showing up in Firebase Console.. I am using Firebase cloud messaging in my node.js webapp

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have a Node.Js with Angular2 Webapp and I am trying to use Firebase cloud messaging for browser notifications. I am successfully able to register to firebase at the front-end. However, when i go to firebase console to take a look at the app and any anaylytics. I see nothing. What could be wrong.

Comment: It takes about 24-48 hours for any analytics to show up in the console AFAIK. In regards to FCM, what analytics data are you looking for? Because AFAICT, FCM logs only exists for messages sent from the console itself.

Comment: Delivery of FCM messages to web clients is indeed currently not tracked in the Firebase console, since that tracking depends on Firebase Analytics, which does not have a Web SDK.